# Resume upload Big files FTP

Tags: ftp, upload

I have a FTP server but I would like to use the resume option to restart an upload in case the connection is lost.

Can FTP do this?

If not is there a file transfer protocol that allows to do such a thing..?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FTP client should support resume transfer.  I prefer [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/client_features.php).

Comment: Yes but it seems that the files get corrupted every time i try to resume my upload any comment on that?

Comment: What happens if the file to be retrieved changes between the resumes?

Comment: In these type of cases, I have sometimes found that my firewall software has causes file corruption.  You might was to try running the upload w/o the firewall being active.

Comment: Any other server that allows uploading resume or just FTP

Answer (score 2):

You'll need both a server and a client that supports `REST` (restart) and `SIZE` which are defined in [RFC-3659](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/rfc/rfc3659.txt).  The server should respond to a `FEAT` command with `REST STREAM`.

Ideally the client and server would support `MDTM` which reports the modification time of a file on the server so the client can decide if the file has been modified since it started transferring.

Answer (score 1):

More specifically, the server does not have the ability to resume a broken file transfer connection.  However, depending on the FTP client being used (not all do this), a resume capability can be implemented in that code.

Answer (score 1):

For something completely different, you could try rsync instead of FTP (assuming you can install it at both client and server and you control any firewalls)